How to get coordinates X and Y from Google map short links?
I want a python script to ask user to input google map links, then print the map coordinates of X and Y.
For a full link like
https://www.google.com/maps/search/29.996966,+68.748251?entry=tts&g_ep=EgoyMDI0MDUyOC4wKgBIAVAD

it is not hard to find x=68.748251 y=29.996966, but for short link like https://maps.app.goo.gl/wsmXZrYfP8V3ur2RA it is not clear.
I have following code currently:
import requests
from urllib.parse import urlparse, parse_qs

def get_coordinates(google_map_short_link):
    # Fetch the full Google Maps link
    response = requests.get(google_map_short_link)
    if response.status_code != 200:
        print("Failed to fetch the full link.")
        return None

    # Extract the full link from the response
    full_link = response.url

    # Parse the URL to extract latitude and longitude
    parsed_url = urlparse(full_link)
    query_params = parse_qs(parsed_url.query)
    coordinates = query_params.get('q')
    if coordinates:
        coordinates = coordinates[0].split(',')
        if len(coordinates) == 2:
            return coordinates[0], coordinates[1]
    return None, None

def main():
    # Ask user for Google Map short link
    google_map_short_link = input("Please enter the Google Maps short link: ")

    # Get coordinates
    x, y = get_coordinates(google_map_short_link)

    # Print coordinates
    print("x =", x)
    print("y =", y)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()


